# How do I find the mode of a column in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is the table and its values:

```
CREATE TABLE Weapon(id INT,
Name VARCHAR(80),
Style VARCHAR(80));

Insert into Weapon values (1, 'Seismic Wand', 'Magic');
Insert into Weapon values (2, 'Nox Bow', 'Ranged');
Insert into Weapon values (3, 'Drygore', 'Melee');
Insert into Weapon values (4, 'Chaotic Staff', 'Magic');
Insert into Weapon values (5, 'Staff of Darkness', 'Magic');
Insert into Weapon values (6, 'Tetsu Katana', 'Melee');
```

Here is my query attempt.

```
SELECT Name, Count(*) AS Style
FROM Weapon
GROUP BY Name
HAVING Count(*) >= ALL
   (SELECT Count(*)
   FROM Weapon
   GROUP BY Name);
```

It is not displaying the mode, the most repeated value of `Style` column.

[image: results]

How do I make it so it displays the mode?

Comment: btw make id an `auto_increment` and therefore PK and don't pass its value

Comment: @Drew: I actually had it at PK but I changed it to a non-PK.

Comment: then that is your actual table schema, with no PK ?

Comment: @sstan.. `mode` is the most frequently occurring item in a group.

Comment: try to keep tags clean, things germane. Ie: `network-programming` also does not belong here :P People roaming thru mysql 5.6 questions don't need to see this

Comment: You have made the word `style` ambiguous.  It's both a field in the table and an alias for the count.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

In response to @vkp's legitimate concerns about the potential for multiple `Style`s being the mode of the data set, here is a better query:

```
SELECT Style AS Mode, COUNT(*) AS Count 
FROM Weapon 
GROUP BY Style 
HAVING COUNT(*) >= ALL (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Weapon GROUP BY Style);
```

This yields:

| Mode | Count |
| --- | --- |
| Magic | 3 |

This will return the mode of the data set and will handle the case where multiple `Style`s are the mode without requiring visual inspection of the results.

For example, building off the original table,

```
INSERT INTO Weapon 
VALUES (7, 'Rock', 'Melee');
```

(to increase the count of 'Melee' so it will tie with 'Magic')

if we run the new mode-finding query we are given these results:

| Mode | Count |
| --- | --- |
| Magic | 3 |
| Melee | 3 |

The original answer I posted (retained below) will produce the mode(s) at the top of the table and requires the user to pick out the value(s) they need. This new solution works better in my opinion. Also, I realize that originally I had labeled my "Count" column as "Mode" when really the mode of the data set is the *name* of the Style (Magic, Melee, etc), *not* the number of times the Style occurs.

---

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:**

For the mode of the Style column,

```
SELECT Style, COUNT(*) AS Mode 
FROM Weapon 
GROUP BY Style 
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;`
```

yielding:

| Style | Mode |
| --- | --- |
| Magic | 3 |
| Melee | 2 |
| Ranged | 1 |

The mode(s) will be at the top of the table.

Thanks to http://www.xarg.org/2012/07/statistical-functions-in-mysql/

Comment: `mode` is the most frequently appearing item in a group. This query doesn't solve that.this just gives the counts.

Comment: @vkp True. It seems to be what the OP wanted, though. To keep things simple, `LIMIT 1` at the end of the query should take care of the case where there is exactly one mode.

Comment: what would happen if there are multiple max values if you use `limit 1`?

Comment: @vkp Like I said, "...the case where there is exactly one mode." If there are multiple max values, then we are moving outside the realm of "keep[ing] things simple" and we'd need a different query. Perhaps yours handles all cases better. With a small table and leaving off the `LIMIT 1` (to visually inspect the results), my solution is apparently acceptable to the OP.

Answer (score 1):

I assume by `mode`, you meant to find all the max repeating item in the table grouped by name.

```
select t2.name from 
(select max(style) as maxstyle from 
(SELECT Name, Count(*) AS Style
FROM Weapon
GROUP BY Name) t) t1
join (SELECT Name, Count(*) AS Style
FROM Weapon
GROUP BY Name) t2 on t1.maxstyle = t2.style
```